# How to get params id in react class component

Tags: reactjs, class, url, parameters, react-class-based-component

I want a params id from the url in this class component

> App.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/products/:id">
       <AuthChecker>
          <Products />
       </AuthChecker>
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

> Products.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    
    class Products extends Component {

     //How to get params id in this class component

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h5></h5>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

   export default Products
```

I did check out some questions but I don't get for class component

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you checked about the class constructor ?

Comment: I tried with the match but it won't work but now it works by passing props match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match.params` for that in combination with `Route's` render prop:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/products/:id" render={({ match }) => (
       <AuthChecker>
          <Products id={match.params.id} />
       </AuthChecker>
    )} />
</Switch>
```